# Unhiding field in a custom list

Tags: 2010, workflow, custom-list

I have a custom list definition and a workflow associated to that list. I got a field that is initially hidden but in my workflow upon activation I try to unhide it:

```
SPListItem currentItem = workflowProperties.Item;
SPWeb curWeb = workflowProperties.Web;
curWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
curWeb.Site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
currentItem.Fields.GetField("AnmerkungenCC").ShowInDisplayForm = true;
currentItem.Fields.GetField("AnmerkungenCC").Hidden = false;
currentItem.Update();
workflowProperties.List.Update();
```

However this seems to have no effect. After the code has run I can't see the column in list settings, display form or any other form. How can I unhide a column so that it is shown in display form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is modifying the list item's fields. Instead modify the list itself using

```
Currentitem.ParentList.Fields["AnmerkungenCC"].Hidden = false;
...
Currentite.parentlist.update()
```

However, this will update the fields for the list so all items will now have the field showing.

Which I don't think is what you want, as if you did why not just have the list setup in that way in the first place?

If you need to hide fields for certain stages of a list items life I suggest looking at custom list forms or using InfoPath.

Comment: This works but as you said isn't what I need. I'll probably have to go with custom forms, thanks anyways!